# changing angular code does not trigger to reload the app inside docker

Tags: angular, docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose

I found [here](https://github.com/DanWahlin/Angular-Docker-Microservices) a docker-compose project:

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: nginx
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: .docker/nginx.dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./dist:/usr/share/nginx/html
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"

    networks:
      - app-network

  node:
    container_name: nodeapp
    image: nodeapp
    build:
      context: ./microservices/node
      dockerfile: .docker/node.development.dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./microservices/node:/var/www/angularnoderestfulservice
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on: 
      - mongodb
    networks:
      - app-network

  #No authentication is provided here - JUST A DEMO! That would absolutely
  #be needed for a "real" application
  mongodb:
    container_name: mongodb
    image: mongo
    networks:
      - app-network

  aspnet:
    container_name: 'aspnetcoreapp'
    image: 'aspnetcoreapp'
    build:
      context: ./microservices/aspnet_core
      dockerfile: .docker/aspnetcore.development.dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./microservices/aspnet_core:/var/www/aspnetcoreapp
    ports:
     - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
     - "postgres"
    networks:
      - app-network

  postgres:
    container_name: 'postgres'
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
    networks:
      - app-network

  cadvisor:
    container_name: cadvisor
    image: google/cadvisor
    volumes:
      - /:/rootfs:ro
      - /var/run:/var/run:rw
      - /sys:/sys:ro
      - /var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:ro
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - app-network

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Unfortunately, when I saved the change of `src/index.html` inside vs code it did not trigger to reload the app inside docker.

What did I miss?

Thank you in advance,

Michal

Comment: Code reload only works with `ng serve`, not with a build version of the Angular code

Comment: Does it mean that is there a way to trigger `ng serve` automatically similar [nodemon --debug=5858](https://youtu.be/vE1iDPx6-Ok)?

Answer (score 0):

When you use nginx to serve, it serves a built version of angular app (by `ng build`) inside /dist folder. You are looking for angular's live development feature with `ng serve`.

Take a look at this repo https://github.com/willcrisis/ng-docker/blob/master/README.md